# PointCollection resource from individual Point resources in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

If I had to create a collection of points as XAML resource, I'd do this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <PointCollection x:Key="points">
        <Point>0,30</Point>
        <Point>20,50</Point>
        <Point>40,10</Point>
    </PointCollection>
</Window.Resources>
```

In my case the points are already resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Point x:Key="a" X="100" Y="100"/>
    <Point x:Key="b" X="200" Y="100"/>
    <Point x:Key="b1a" X="100" Y="0"/>
    <Point x:Key="b1b" X="200" Y="0"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

and this way (which is probably already over-killing) doesn't work, as X/Y are not dependency properties:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <PointCollection x:Key="b1points">
        <Point X="{Binding Source={StaticResource b1a}, Path=X}"
               Y="{Binding Source={StaticResource b1a}, Path=Y}"/>
        <Point X="{Binding Source={StaticResource b1b}, Path=X}"
               Y="{Binding Source={StaticResource b1b}, Path=Y}"/>
        <Point X="{Binding Source={StaticResource b}, Path=X}"
               Y="{Binding Source={StaticResource b}, Path=Y}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

The collection is used in a Bezier segment later:

```
<PolyBezierSegment Points="{StaticResource b1points}"/>
```

but the points must be declared individually, so that they can be used like:

```
<Ellipse Canvas.Left="{Binding Source={StaticResource a}, Path=X}"
         Canvas.Top="{Binding Source={StaticResource a}, Path=Y}"
         Width="3" Height="3" Fill="Red"/>
```

Is someone able to suggest a mean in XAML? and even more difficult, without a converter?

Comment: Why don't you have a view model that provides the points and the PointCollection?

Comment: @Clemens: I'm learning XAML, and wanted to know how to do it in XAML only

Comment: As a note, if you wanted to draw the Ellipse centered at a certain point, you would have to subtract half of its Width and Height from Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top. Or you use a Path with an EllipseGeometry, which already has a Center property of type Point.

Comment: @Clemens: Of course.

Comment: And even if you use the individual Points as binding source objects, you do not strictly need to declare them as individual resources, because you could write `Center="{Binding Source={StaticResource points}, Path=[0]}"`.

Comment: @Clemens: Good point,  but an individual point may appear in several collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Point x:Key="a" X="100" Y="100"/>
    <Point x:Key="b" X="200" Y="100"/>
    <Point x:Key="b1a" X="100" Y="0"/>
    <Point x:Key="b1b" X="200" Y="0"/>

    <PointCollection x:Key="b1points">
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="b1a"/>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="b1b"/>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="a"/>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="b"/>
    </PointCollection>
</Window.Resources>

...

<PolyBezierSegment Points="{StaticResource b1points}"/>

...

<Path Fill="Red">
    <Path.Data>
        <EllipseGeometry Center="{StaticResource a}" RadiusX="1.5" RadiusY="1.5"/>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: Why I didn't think to this?? Thanks for the additional Ellipse tip.